# Why is R. Daneel able to approach Dr. Leebig without announcing he is a robot?

Tags: isaac-asimov, laws-of-robotics

I finished reading "The Naked Sun" by Isaac Asimov and cannot figure out why Daneel would be able to approach Dr. Leebig in person without first identifying himself as a robot. We know that Dr. Leebig and all other Solarians experience significant emotional stress and even anguish at in-person interactions with other humans. Daneel is also aware of this but seems to have no issue with being on hand to perform the arrest in person. This seems a clear violation of the first law of robotics.

Is this a plot hole or something the author purposely left unclear? It appears Asimov had the opportunity to address this as before Daneel goes to make the arrest Detective Baley asks him if he has any reservations under the first law. To which Daneel has no issues.

Comment: In one of the books, The Robots of Dawn IIRC, it is stated that the three laws aren't as simple as they appear when put to words, but that they actually highly complex and precise equations that assign weights to possible actions (exact phrasing here is my own, as I don't remember exactly how Mr. Asimov put it). I'm guessing that bringing a criminal to justice was deemed more important than not causing said criminal distress.

Comment: I am about to start that book so it will be interesting to see if it provides an answer. There are some robots with differently weighted laws in I, Robot so I had considered it. I can't recall any mention of Daneel having altered weights though.

Comment: I'm not saying Daneel's weights are altered, simply that the laws are mathematiical, and that they provide much higher precision in determining the correct action than the worded form of the laws do.

Comment: If that's so though, how is the "Zeroth Law" later able to supersede the first?